# Swapping using Knockout js sortable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, swap

I have a square grid with 5*5 squares inside it. I want to swap two squares (ie) when i drag a square and drop it on another square both the squares should get swapped changing their positions. But since am using sortable some other squares positions are getting changed. Is this behaviour possible in knockout js ???

Answer (score 0):

The `sortable` binding accepts a `beforeMove` callback that is passed an object that contains the `sourceParent`, `sourceIndex`, `targetParent`, and `targetIndex`.  You could use these to do the swap yourself.

Also, you can set `arg.cancelDrop = true;` to indicate that you will handle it yourself.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/c7NLz/